# how to get image path on server in dotnet

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, itext, razor-pages

hello i'm working on EXPORT document to PdF in dotnet core, but doc contains Images I used the following code to retrieve image which is working on for my localhost but when I push code to server I'm getting 500 error, issue with image path.

```
var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "EDSignature.png");
_logger.LogInformation($"EDSignature Image {path}");
//var path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("Images/EDSignature.png")?.PhysicalPath;
var EDSignature = Image.GetInstance(path);
//var EDSignature = Image.GetInstance($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\images\EDSignature.png"}");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndF4p.png)

Comment: What is the actual error message? You should start with that to establish the cause of your issue.

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, and moving the `images` folder under the wwwroot folder solved the problem. If the `images` folder is already under the wwwroot folder, please ignore this paragraph.

In addition, the key to your problem is that this folder and file were not included in the release. You can add below code in your .csproj file. You also need to learn the options of CopyToOutputDirectory.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\images\*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```